# Which Nuget Packages for use with Azure Offline Data Sync

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure

I was following the demo for Azure Offline Data Sync (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data/). When adding the references to SQLite there does not seem to be Nuget packages listed in the demo.  I cannot find SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1) or SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1.  Is there an appropriate substitute?

Also why can't SQLite run on both Arm and x86.  When I choose x86 as recommended, I cannot deploy to my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the nuget: **`Azure Mobile SQLiteStore 2.0.1`**.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore/

Comment: Try to do a Clean Solution and Rebuild Solution?

Comment: When I do that it adds references to SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1) or SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1, just like the example, but Visual Studio gives me two errors "Could not find SDK 'SQLite.WinRT81, version=3.8.7.2'" and "Could not find SDK 'SQLite.WP81, version=3.8.7.2'."

Comment: This is the third time I've done this with the exact same results.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  I went to http://sqlite.org/download.html and ran the sqlite-wp81-winrt-3110100.vsix and sqlite-winrt81-3110100.vsix.  I added the references through "add reference" and "extensions".  I removed the invalid references.